# How can I find which value caused a bson.errors.InvalidStringData

Tags: mongodb, exception, pymongo, bson

I have a system that reads data from various sources and stores them in MongoDB. The data I receive is already properly encoded in utf-8 or in unicode. Documents are loosely related and vary greatly in *schema*, if you will.

Every now and then, a document has a field value that is pure binary data, like a JPEG image. I know how to wrap that value in a `bson.binary.Binary` object to avoid the `bson.errors.InvalidStringData` exception.

Is there a way to tell which part of a document made pymongo driver to raise a `bson.errors.InvalidStringData`, or do I have to try and convert each field to find it ?

(+If by chance a binary object happens to be a valid unicode string or utf-8, it will be stored as a string and that's ok)

Comment: Could you please note when does pymongo throws `InvalidStringData` in your case? I'm asking because you've said that the data is encoded in UTF-8, but, as documentation says, this error is raised while reading non-UTF8 data ([docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.InvalidStringData)). Thanks.

Comment: It is when a document has a field value that is pure binary data, like a JPEG image or a X509 certificate. I never get this error on strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyMongo has two BSON implementations, one in Python for portability and one in C for speed. `_make_c_string` in the Python version will tell you what it failed to encode but the C version, which is evidently what you're using, does not. You can tell which BSON implementation you have with `import bson; bson.has_c()`. I've filed [PYTHON-533](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-533), it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: Indeed, `bson.has_c()` returns `True`. I'll accept your answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question)

You can't tell from the exception, and some rewrite of the driver would be required to support that feature.

The code is in [`bson/__init__.py`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/__init__.py). There is a function named `_make_c_string` that raises `InvalidStringData` if string throws a UnicodeError if it is to be encoded in utf-8. The same function is **used for both keys and values** that are strings.

In other words, at this point in code, the driver does not know if it is dealing with a key or value.

The offending data *is* passed as a raw string to the exception's constructor, but for a reason I don't understand, it does not come out of the driver.

```
>>> bad['zzz'] = '0\x82\x05\x17'
>>> try:
...     db.test.insert(bad)
... except bson.errors.InvalidStringData as isd:
...     print isd
...
strings in documents must be valid UTF-8
```

But that does not matter: you would have to look up the keys for that value anyway.

The best way is to iterate over the values, trying to decode them in utf-8. If a `UnicodeDecodeError` is raised, wrap the value in a Binary object.

Somewhat like this :

```
try:
    #This code could deal with other encodings, like latin_1
    #but that's not the point here
    value.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    value = bson.binary.Binary(str(value))
```